# reg:xml function not getting union all

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have used this query to get result as using XMLagg as concatenation string error  was frmo table.

I am trying to do process ws_router group by and contract  column in list for only process ws_router,
Other  process_name also and other details we want to show in output but contract list only for process ws_router.

```
select 
TO_CHAR(EVENT_MINUTE, 'MM-YYYY') AS EVENT_MINUTE,
--substr( XMLCast( XMLAgg(XMLElement(e, ','||APPLICATION)order by APPLICATION)as clob), 2) APP_LIST,
PROCESS_NAME,
  substr(
    XMLCast(
      XMLAgg(
        XMLElement(e, ','||CONTRACT)
        order by CONTRACT
      )
      as clob
    ), 2
  ) CONTRACT_LIST,

APPLICATION AS APPLICATION, 
SUM(TOTAL_COUNT) AS TOTAL_COUNT, SUM(TOTAL_COUNT)-SUM(COUNT_FAILED) AS SUCCESS_TRANS, ROUND(AVG(AVG_DURATION),2) AS AVG_DURATION, 
ROUND((SUM(TOTAL_COUNT)-SUM(COUNT_FAILED))/SUM(TOTAL_COUNT)*100) AS SUCCESS_PERCENTAGE FROM STATS_TRACK_SUMMARY_BY_MIN 
WHERE EVENT_MINUTE >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC (SYSDATE,'MM'), - 3) AND CONTRACT <> 'NULL' AND APPLICATION IN ('fastbpm','FASTBPM')
AND PROCESS_NAME='ws_router'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(EVENT_MINUTE, 'MM-YYYY'),APPLICATION, PROCESS_NAME 
ORDER BY 
TO_DATE(EVENT_MINUTE,'MM-YYYY')
union all
select TO_CHAR(EVENT_MINUTE, 'MM-YYYY') AS EVENT_MINUTE, process_name, application, contract contract_list,
  sum(total_count) as total_count,
  sum(total_count)-sum(count_failed) as success_trans,
  round(avg(avg_duration),2) as avg_duration,
  round((sum(total_count)-sum(count_failed))/sum(total_count)*100) as success_percentage
from stats_track_summary_by_min
where process_name != 'ws_router'
and EVENT_MINUTE >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC (SYSDATE,'MM'), - 3) AND CONTRACT <> 'NULL' AND APPLICATION IN ('fastbpm','FASTBPM')
group by  TO_CHAR(EVENT_MINUTE, 'MM-YYYY'),
CONTRACT, APPLICATION, PROCESS_NAME ORDER BY TO_date(EVENT_MINUTE,'MM-YYYY');
```

below is output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc0XJ.png)

requsted ouput

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS in question. Oracle?

Comment: Example data might also be needed / helpful